# No installer in ISO

Tags: installation, boot, iso

I have downloaded ubuntu 13.04 and installed all the needed softwares , java , browsers and customized as I required and I made a iso with Remastersys software . I have used it before many times so it was easy to make out one. I burn it to a DVD and when I try booting it up , it actually boots up but there is no " installer " to install it. So how to install it . I tried opting " start installer directly " from boot menu but still it comes into desktop . I can use it like a OS but how to install it on my hard drive ??

I am attaching the Log file details here to verify. Help me out guys !

[Remastersys Log File](http://www.mediafire.com/download/0lo8wzkoq8qopcp/remastersys.log)

[md5sum](http://www.mediafire.com/download/56shagtbyoi6y98/SAGAR_OS_13.04_64bit.iso.md5)

Comment: Line `304 ...ready to be burned or tested in a virtual machine.` says that its ready to be tested, but I couldn't find any reference to an installer in the log file... I do not know anything about this and may have misunderstood your question when I answered below.

Answer (score 2):

When you boot from the Live CD, and you get to the desktop, you should see an item on the launch bar on the left saying install. this should start you on the path you are looking for.

If it's not there, try searching the programmes for the installer <kbd>Super</kbd> click on the **A** (Application icon) at the bottom of the pane then type in the programme name.

If it's not there, when you created the iso file, you may have not included, or over written it when you added the browsers and other software.

Another option is to install from the iso from the Ubuntu website then add the different programmes and browsers from the installed desktop?

Comment: Hello dear , The option "Install" is not there on the desktop and I already had searched for the same in the dashboard but failed to find any. If I can add an installer to the ISO file , then please let me know how ? This could be the possible way I hope so.

Comment: Hi SAGAR,  I don't know if http://askubuntu.com/questions/264712/ubuntu-installer-doesnt-start-from-a-separate-iso-partition-unetbootin will help.